# remote debugging asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a server running my web app through IIS.  I have visual studio locally, I am attaching to the remote w3wp.exe process with no issues, but my breakpoints are not being hit because my symbols are not loaded.

[image: What am I missing?]

What am i missing?

Update: Should I be debugging Native or Managed?  When I do Native, the Modules window shows a ton of windows dll's that all fail to open the PDB. Should I be concerned? I do not see my dll in the list.  When I use Managed, the modules window is completely empty.

Comment: Have you tried coping the PDB files locally?

Comment: I have the pdb files locally, but my understanding is that to debug remotely you have to point the symbols file at the remote dir.

Comment: They don't have to be remote; as long as they're the same PDB files so that the checksum matches.  The PDB files will need to know where the source code is; if the PDB files were generated on your local machine, it should have no problem finding the source code.

Comment: I have now tried with both local and remote paths to no avail

Comment: When you're attached, if you click Debug/Windows/Modules, you can view the symbol load information for each DLL.  You might see information in there that indicates why the symbols could not be loaded.  Is there anything useful?

Comment: hmm. no. there is nothing at all, and the right click option to load symbols is greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue.  When I was attaching to the process via the Visual Studio gui, the w3wp.exe process was listed as x86 instead of Managed 4.0.  I recreated my app's site in IIS and the process went back to being listed as Managed, which allowed the symbols to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you built your project in debug mode. Also, make sure you have sufficient rights for your remote server.

Comment: I am publishing in debug mode and see the PDB server side. What do i check rights wise on the server?

Comment: When you browser the project folder on the server do you see the pdb files?

Comment: I see the one pdb for my project, yes, located in \\192.168.42.10\httpd\html\Chat\bin

Comment: You don't need debug mode for symbols to work; you just need the symbols.